# How to configure an anaconda shell on windows terminal but with powershell 7

Tags: powershell, anaconda, windows-terminal

Anaconda is already installed on my computer. Window propose me an anaconda shell.
I followed this [tutorial](https://dev.to/azure/easily-add-anaconda-prompt-in-windows-terminal-to-make-life-better-3p6j) to add the anaconda shell as proposed shell by windows terminal.
I means that I have added the following json element in settings.json

```
{
    commandline": "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -NoExit -Command \"& 'C:\\Users\\gendraup\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1'",
    guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87fa24bf}",
    hidden": false,
    name": "anaconda PowerShell",
    startingDirectory": "C:\\Users\\gendraup"
}
```

Now a powershell with anaconda is proposed by windows terminal. But I want to use powershell 7 not windows powershell.

I have install powershell 7 with microsoft app. I didn't have to configure windows terminal
This line was already install for me.

```
        {
            "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "PowerShell",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore"
        },
```

I tried to replace "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe " with Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore. in anaconda shell configuration. It doesn't work.

I tried to search the reach path of powershell 7 but windows doesn't propose to open the app location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open powershell 7
go to task explorer.

Right click on the powershell task explorer.
Open the file directory.

In my case I get this path

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_7.3.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\pwsh.exe

and for the moment it looks it's working as expecting for now

this code solve the problem but I m curious to know if there a simple way to reuse source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore" without searching the file path